# Python while loop not ending when list empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I was trying to find out a way to perform in-order tree transversal iteratively without using a tuple. Not sure why but the list is going from [] to [None] and runs the while loop one more time
https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/description/

> ```
> def inorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
>     stack = [root]
>     res = []
>     while stack:
>         print("start",stack)
>         curr = stack.pop()
>         if curr.left:
>             temp = curr.left
>             curr.left = None
>             if curr.right:
>                 stack.append(curr.right)
>                 curr.right = None
>             stack.append(curr)
>             stack.append(temp)
>         else:
>             res.append(curr.val)
>             if curr.right:
>                 stack.append(curr.right)
>         print("end",stack)
>     return res
> ```

when running this code with testcase [1], the output when printing is

```
start [TreeNode{val: 1, left: None, right: None}]
end []
start [None]
```

this means at the end of the while loop stack = [], so the while loop should end. However, all of a sudden the stack = [None] and runs one more loop. Very confused why this happens. I put a print in front of every append but found nothing. It is solved by adding a check for if curr is None but I still have no idea why this happens. If anyone knows please help!

**UPDATE:**
Copy and pasted into hackerrank's same question and it worked properly. Could this be a bug in leetcode?????
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/tree-inorder-traversal/problem

Comment: Never modify a list you are iterating over. There are better ways to do it that don't run into serious problems.

Comment: Doesn't seem like this code should be able to print that result -- you never break the loop, so each iteration should print both `start` and `end`.  Are you positive this is the version of the code you're running?

Comment: Ya, I tried it on leetcode multiple times. The reason why it doesn't print an end the last time is because it runs into a curr is none so doesn't have a left error and doesn't finish running to the second print. Could you try and let me know if u get anything different?

Comment: The only way this code could have produced that output is if `inorderTraversal()` had been called *twice* - once with a one-element Tree, once with None as the root.  (Your type hint on the `root` parameter claims that None is a valid value, but your code doesn't actually handle that case.)

Comment: i think its a bug with leetcode where it errors all testcases if it is an Attribute error that shows up in just one testcase

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming what you are trying to do here is convert a tree to an in-order list of elements to look at. It is possible you're trying to do something else, but if so, it is unclear.

```
def inOrderTraversal(ls: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
    // Recurse into the left branch
    if isinstance(ls.left, int):
        left = [ls.left]
    else:  // Assumes left is a TreeNode
        left = inOrderTraversal(ls.left)

    // Recurse into the right branch
    if isintance(ls.right, int):
        right = [ls.right]
    else:
        right = inOrderTraversal(ls.right)

    return left + right
```

This almost certainly won't work right out of the box, but it is a demonstration of what you're going for. You need to determine if the left branch should be recursed down, then the right. If the left or right branches are simply ints, then you need to add them as elements.

Your `while` loop is a misdirection - you are already setting `stack` to be a list of length one (the root element). The `while` loop isn't doing anything since you have only one element. You do not need to set anything to `None` for this sort of task - just forget about whatever you were iterating over once you have the data you need.

Comment: I get what you mean. I was able to do the problem recursively but wanted to think of a way to do it iteratively without having to use tuple. Normally iterative solutions look like this:

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/solutions/713539/python-3-all-iterative-traversals-inorder-preorder-postorder-similar-solutions/

Comment: You're not doing it iteratively in your example code, though - and on some level anything you do *will* be recursive because you are starting out with a tree.

Comment: I also think you're rather significantly misunderstanding the link you posted. It is not speaking to recursion or iterative approaches, it is speaking to the ordering of nodes within a tree.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. As other users have alluded to, there is indeed a bug in LeetCode. If you remove Case 2 before clicking Run, then you will find your code executes well.

The issue was that LeetCode somehow ran the test cases simultaneously, and so your code bugged out on Case 2, when `root==None`. In this case, your stack starts with a None element, so you actually enter your `while` loop, and then you have issues.

You can quickly fix your code by adding the base case `if root==None: return []` at the beginning of your function.